# Generate xml from Java pojo without using annotations

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need to marshal Java pojo(s) into xml, and pojo are part of an API so I can't make any changes, like adding any jaxb annotations, is there any other way of converting these Java objecta in xml (for ex. any API like Jackson etc..) without using annotations.

Comment: Use `STAX` \ `SAX`-parcer or `DOM`-parcer

Comment: You do not need any annotations. Just see example on [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stax`-parser.

`Device`-class (for example):

```
public class Device {

    private String name;
    private String model;

    public Device(String name, String model) {
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
    }

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Parse **Object** to **xml** use `XMLStreamWriter`:

```
List<Device> deviceList = ...

StringWriter stringWriter= new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter = XMLOutputFactory
            .newFactory()
            .createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);

xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\n");
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("devices");     // write <devices>
xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\n");

for(Device d : deviceList){
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\t");
    xmlWriter.writeStartElement("device");  // write <device>
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\n\t\t");
    xmlWriter.writeStartElement("name");    // write <name>
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters(d.getName()); // write <name> value
    xmlWriter.writeEndElement();            // write </name>
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\n\t\t");
    xmlWriter.writeStartElement("model");   // write <model>
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters(d.getModel());// write <model> value
    xmlWriter.writeEndElement();            // write </name>
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\n\t");
    xmlWriter.writeEndElement();            // write </device>
    xmlWriter.writeCharacters("\n");
 }
 xmlWriter.writeEndElement();               // write </devices>
 xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
 xmlWriter.close();

 System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());         // print result
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<devices>
  <device>
    <name>iPhone</name>
    <model>6s</model>
  </device>
  <device>
    <name>iPhone</name>
    <model>7</model>
  </device>
  <device>
    <name>iPad</name>
    <model>2</model>
  </device>
</devices>
```